# word matching with exploits

Tags: php, string

I have kept filter which filter out some blocked words like `ass`, `jerk` etc. I have list of such words to compare and block if exist.

some users use them like `je*k`, `f*ck` so they are not matched with list and words appear on page. Is there any way to overcome this exploit?

similarly for `shit` user uses `sh/t`. how can I handle such issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a function that I use on my framework for comments ect, it loads a [large list of filters words](https://gist.github.com/lcherone/6f8043447f7f0099d430) and uses word boundary's to replace with `*`, in the word list I use `*` as the wildcard letter so as not to replace words like chickenjerk, when i detect an exploit ill just add it to the list.

```
/**
 * Swear word filtering function, requires a list of words,
 * Second parameter reveals *n letters
 *
 * @param string $str
 * @param int $reveal
 * @return string
 */
function swear_filter($str, $reveal=null) {
    //load words from file, triming any whitespace
    //$words = join("|", array_filter(array_map('preg_quote',array_map('trim', file('./path/to/badwords.txt')))));

    $words = 'ass|jerk|je*k|f*ck|sh\/t|sh*t*';//<< comment this out when you set path to word list
    if($reveal !=null && is_numeric($reveal)){
        return preg_replace("/\b($words)\b/uie", '"".substr("$1",0,'.$reveal.').str_repeat("*",strlen("$1")-'.$reveal.').""', $str);
    }else{
        return preg_replace("/\b($words)\b/uie", '"".str_repeat("*",strlen("$1")).""', $str);
    }
}
//I like chickenjerk, you **** **** ***
echo swear_filter('I like chickenjerk, you jerk sh/t ass.');

//I like chickenjerk, you j*** s*** a**.
echo swear_filter('I like chickenjerk, you jerk sh/t ass.', 1); //with reveal
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks a lot Loz, but I coult not understand use of 2nd parameter here

Comment: try it, `echo swear_filter('I like chickenjerk, you jerk sh/t ass.', 1);` would produce `I like chickenjerk, you j*** s*** a**.`

Comment: np, i spent many hours trying to figure out this predicament, its the best i could come up with without manually checking every post. Its not perfect though, nothing like human intervention.

Comment: what does `$1` indicate, if you add little description about return values then it would be more clear

Comment: Its the matched word from the regex match.

Answer (score 3):

If you are checking individual words you can use [`levenshtein()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php)

```
if (!ctype_alpha($text) && levenshtein('shit', $text) === 1) {
    //match
}
```

Comment: This way, similar words such as "_shot_" wouldn't be accepted as well

Comment: What you could do, is use an algorithm like that to put words like that in a queue for a moderator. Then a moderator can either white-list or black-list them to improve future matches. A lot of overhead for a longer text though...

Comment: @kingkero True, I added a check that only looks at non alphabetic strings. Someone could still get around it with only alphabetic words such as shlt but it shouldn't have false positives

Comment: @FuzzyTree I didn't know of `ctype_alpha` - thx! Also I believe if somebody wants to post an insult no matter what, he will do so anyway. So this code should be quite helpful